# What's the best way to keep adding to an array of objects in n-dimensions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to give an array of objects two dimensions, depth and height, and then create a nested array with those dimensions.  The `desiredArr` at the bottom would be an example of a 4 X 2.

```
var x = 4;
var y = 2;
var arr = [{
                "key":[],
                "num":Math.random()
}, //etc...];

for(var m=0; m<y; m++){
  for(var n=0; n<x; n++){
    //I want something like the following: 
    //arr[0][key][1][key][m].push( ... ) ? 
    arr[0]['key'].push({
        "key":[],
        "num":Math.random()
    });

  }
}
console.log(arr)



var desiredArr = [
  {
  'num':3,
  'key':[{
    'num':3.4,
    'key':[{
      'num':2.3,
      'key':[{
        'num':1.3,
        'key':[{}]
      }]
    }]
  }]
  },{
  'num':5,
  'key':[{
    'num':2.4,
    'key':[{
      'num':1.3,
      'key':[{
        'num':5.3,
        'key':[{}]
      }]
    }]
  }]
  }
]
console.log(desiredArr)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4yk5b7Lq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var depth = 4;
var dim = 2;

function build(curDepth) {
  if (curDepth <= 0) return {};
  return {
    num: Math.random(),
    key: [ build(curDepth -1) ]
  };
}

var nestedObj = [];
for(var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
  nestedObj.push(build(depth));
}
console.log(nestedObj);
```

This uses recursion to give you a more readable solution. The key portion recurses down from the starting depth until it reaches 0.

The `num` part can be factored to give you the number range and level of precision you want, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to keep a reference to the object in the deepest level of your nested array–object structure.

Something like this creates an array of length `y` with `x` nested `num`–`key` objects.

```js
var arr = [],
  x = 4,
  y = 2,
  obj,
  tmpObj;

for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
  obj = {};
  arr.push(obj);
  for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
    obj.num = Math.random();
    obj.key = [];
    tmpObj = {};
    obj.key.push(tmpObj);
    obj = tmpObj;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```